# Button Click Operation/ Click again, does opposite?

Tags: c#, timer, visual-studio-2013

In VS2013, how do I make it so that if you click a button, it will do something and if you click it again, it will do the opposite?

So for example,

- User -> Click `Pause`

  `timer1.Enabled = false;`
- User -> Click `Pause` Again

  `timer1.Enabled = true;`

Comment: You may want to add somethinhg like this: `button1.Text = timer1.Enabled ? "Stop" : "Start";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use this code in your button click handler:

```
timer1.Enabled = !timer1.Enabled;
```

It will simply invert the boolean value